# Can't see custom field after the Loop

Tags: loop, advanced-custom-fields

I have created a loop to show some products on my wordpress site and they seem to be working fine they reel out the products however if I place one of custom fields after the loop it doesn't show. I know its not an issue with the custom field itself as it works fine if I put it above the loop. Does anyone know where I could be going wrong?

Here is my code:

http://pastebin.com/SVxYK0XP

Thanks

Comment: Please include *relevant code* in your question. Links will go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you output your `get_posts` results and do this:

```
setup_postdata($post);
```

You overwrite the original value of `$post` which `the_field` uses to fetch the field data. It's trying to get that field belonging to the last post in `$products_mono_posts` instead of the page that the field actually belongs to.

After running custom queries where the value of the global `$post` is modified, you need to call [`wp_reset_postdata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) to restore the value of `$post` to its original value.